# SageMath: Getting the imaginary part of a matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, sage

Suppose you have a matrix with complex entries, and you would like to extract the imaginary component of each entry and make a new matrix in Sage. For instance, suppose

```py
M = [[1 + 2i, 5 + 3*i], [5, 3*i]]
```

I would like to get

```py
M_imag = [[2, 3], [0, 3]]
```

I am aware that `z.imag()` returns the imaginary part of a complex number `z` in sage. Also the following code works for vectors:
`[z.real() for z in v]`
but I cannot get it to work for matrices.

I know [then NumPy library provides the means for this](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.imag.html). But I do not want to change the Sage matrix to numpy. Ultimately, if there is a way to change a NumPy matrix back to Sage, that will work too. I prefer a solution that is independent from other libraries, including NumPy.

How can this be achieved in Sage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beware that this really defines a list of lists, not a matrix:

```py
sage: M = [[1 + 2*i, 5 + 3*i], [5, 3*i]]
```

so that it displays like a list of lists:

```py
sage: M
[[2*I + 1, 3*I + 5], [5, 3*I]]
```

and its "parent" is the class of lists:

```py
sage: parent(M)
<class 'list'>
```

To define a matrix, use `matrix` of a list of lists (or of a NumPy array):

```py
sage: M = matrix([[i, 3], [5, i]])
```

It displays as a matrix:

```py
sage: M
[I 3]
[5 I]
```

and lives in a space of matrices:

```py
sage: parent(M)
Full MatrixSpace of 2 by 2 dense matrices
over Number Field in I with defining polynomial x^2 + 1 with I = 1*I
```

Change a whole row or a single entry as follows:

```py
sage: M[0, :] = matrix([[2*I + 1, 3*I + 5]])
sage: M[1, 1] = 3*I
```

and see the result:

```py
sage: M
[2*I + 1 3*I + 5]
[      5     3*I]
```

Get LaTeX code for the matrix:

```py
sage: latex(M)
sage: latex(M)
\left(\begin{array}{rr}
2 i + 1 & 3 i + 5 \\
5 & 3 i
\end{array}\right)
```

See the matrix nicely typeset:

```py
sage: view(M)
```

Compute the trace and determinant:

```py
sage: M.trace()
5*I + 1
sage: M.det()
-12*I - 31
```

Apply a map to each entry, e.g. `real` or `imag` to get the real part or imaginary part:

```py
sage: A = M.apply_map(real)
sage: B = M.apply_map(imag)
```

and check the result:

```py
sage: A, B, A + i*B, M
(
[1 5]  [2 3]  [2*I + 1 3*I + 5]  [2*I + 1 3*I + 5]
[5 0], [0 3], [      5     3*I], [      5     3*I]
)
```

Further reading

- [Robert A. Beezer. A first course in linear algebra.](http://linear.pugetsound.edu/fcla/front-matter.html)

Answer (score 2):

I think this will solve your problem `[[z.imag() for z in v] for v in M]`. You iterate over the rows in M and then you iterate over the elements in each row and compute the imaginary part of it.

Comment: Thanks @Lisa! I cannot believe your "I hope this helps" got removed in an edit. Anyways, it certainly helped. A slight modification to your code gives me exactly what I was expecting: `Matrix([[z.imag() for z in v] for v in M])`. This gives me the same output as `M.apply_map(imag)` as indicated in the other answer. It appears `M.apply_map(imag)` is slightly faster too.